# A div that can't be broken

Tags: html, css

This is more theoretical, I don't have a use for it currently, but would be nice. I would like to create a div layout in which each section cannot be broken by mismatched tags inside of it.

A simple model:

```
<div id="navbar">

</div>

<div id="content">


**blah blah blah </div>**<!-- assume this line came from a php include -->

blah blah blah

</div><!-- still related to #content despite the bogus /div above it. -->
```

Has anyone ever tried to accomplish this, or is this a fools errand?

Comment: How is it related to #content? Was it not closed by the bogus closing div tag?

Comment: `"is this a fools errand"` - I think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this. If you have an opening `<div>` tag, the next `</div>` tag will close it. Period. Case closed.

If you don't want your `<div>` to be closed early, then don't print the bogus `</div>`.

Answer (score 2):

There's always

```
<div>

<![CDATA[ blah blah </div> ]]>

</div>
```

But then you can't really make use of the tags inside the CDATA section.

Comment: And you're still vulnerable to `]]>`, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Frames (inline or otherwise) provide some isolation. Anything inside the frame won't close tags outside the frame.

Answer (score 1):

That does happen but the solution is sanitizing what you will output properly, this `**blah blah blah </div>**<!-- assume this line came from a php include -->` should not be printed, strip the tags or check for valid html before doing so.